# hostapd: why only 65mbps?

Tags: hostapd

compare my router fritz with raspberry pi4 + hostapd

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID         MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  >
        *****************  Fritzrouter  Infra  1     260 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  >
*       *****************  Rasprouter   Infra  7     65 Mbit/s   69      ▂▄▆_
```

As you can see the fritz router has powerful signal and rate, hostapd only 65Mbit.
Is not possible to obtain more?

This is the hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
ssid=Router2
hw_mode=g
channel=7
macaddr_acl=1
accept_mac_file=/etc/hostapd/accept
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mypass
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
country_code=IT
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211ac=1         
wmm_enabled=1
```

Comment: Is your WiFi MTU 1500? See `ip link`. It should be 1492, or you'll spend a lot of time doing packet fragmentation/reassembly.

Comment: Is 1500 on server and client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, with a [good adapter](https://www.brostrend.com/products/brostrend-linux-chiavetta-wifi-usb-a-lunga-portata-1200-mbps) and a good configuration we can reach good speed.

```
wlan1     IEEE 802.11AC  ESSID:"MMMM"  Nickname:"WIFI@RTL88X2BU"
          Mode:Master  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: *******   
          Bit Rate:867 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=1/100  Signal level=1/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

This is the hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan1
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
ssid=mysid
hw_mode=a
channel=36
ieee80211d=1
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211ac=1
wmm_enabled=1
macaddr_acl=1
accept_mac_file=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.accept
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mysid
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
country_code=IT

#HT
require_ht=1
require_vht=1
ht_capab=[MAX-AMSDU-7935][HT40+][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40]
```